# Why can't I detect concept drift with linear regression?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, noise, concept-drift, data-drift

When I was first trying to detect concept drift, it seemed naively to me to be a problem of detecting whether noisy data was veering off horizontal trajectory (non-trivial slope above some arbitrary threshold that I'd consider a statistically significant slope).

I have a deployed model that's been predicting for months. I sampled data from each month, and then split those samples into segments, and in each segment kept track of a label's frequency in that dataset proportional to the size of it - the amount of times the label was predicted in the segment divided by the overall number of datapoints in the segment. I end up with noisy data $L$, and I'd imagine if drift were to occur that $L$ would have some sufficiently non-trivial slope.

There are lots of fancy methods I could use to detect drift using `skmultiflow` like `ADWIN`, but the first thing that came to mind was simple linear regression. Why can't I just fit a line to  the noisy data and see if its slope is not constant? Or, what if I used `tsmoothie` to smooth the noisy data and fit a line on that? Am I oversimplifying things, and that's why methods like `ADWIN` exist?

Say, for instance, I used `tsmoothie` and ended up with the following smoothed signal:

[image]

What's stopping me from taking a linear regression of that dark blue line?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! That dark blue line looks not to have an increasing or a decreasing trend, so what would you hope to learn from such a regression?

Comment: That there isn't a decreasing or increasing trend, hence an approximately trivial slope and therefore no concept drift. The y-axis has to do with the frequency of a label divided by the size of the dataset it was frequented from. I just want a programmatic way to show no concept drift, and was wondering if linear regression was too naive a solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are two troubling aspects to that.

1. Just because you get an insignificant regression slope doesn’t mean a lack of drift. It could just mean a lack of ability to detect the drift due to lacking power in the hypothesis test. These are different. If you are able to declare an effect size of interest (so a slope that would make you take notice and wonder what is happening), however, then techniques like [equivalence testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_test) and TOST can be valuable.
2. Depending on what kind of drift there is, linear regression might not be able to detect it. For instance, linear regression will totally miss a sinusoidal pattern where you drift and then return, drift and then return, drift and then return. If that sounds okay, that’s just one of infinitely many possibilities that a linear regression will miss. (Yes, linear regression can use nonlinear basis functions to model sinusoidal patterns. However, you have to tell then regression to use that basis function, and that requires you to determine, ahead of time, what you want to detect.)

Comment: 1. By "lacking power in the hypothesis test", does that mean lacking enough of a regression slope to deem it as statistically significant?

2. If drift is sinusoidal, could one posit that, on average, there is no drift occurring? There is always a drift in the case of a sinusoid, but you could argue it's "self-correcting".

Comment: 1) That’s exactly what I mean. Absence of evidence is not the same as evidence of absence. This is the usual business about not accepting a null hypothesis. // 2) You can take that stance if it makes sense for your application. However, that is a decision you have to make, and the specific example of a sinusoidal pattern is just one example of what a simple linear regression would struggle to detect.